# Ubuntu 16.04 boots in tty mode

Tags: 16.04, bash, startup, gui

My Ubuntu 16.04 is suddenly started booting in to the tty1 mode. I'm not able to use gui by pressing `ctrl+alt+f7`. When I login in tty mode it says

```
-bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I also tried `startx` and got this error

```
-bash: /usr/bin/startx: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How could I solve this problem and Why this happened suddenly?

Comment: what happens when you do `sudo ln -s /bin/dash /bin/sh`?

Comment: @Zanna `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/bin/sh': File exists`

Comment: and `readlink -e /bin/sh` ?

Comment: @Zanna It returns nothing

Comment: there's your problem... can you `sudo apt install dash`?

Comment: @Zanna It calims that `dash is already the newest version (0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2).`

Comment: I guess I should have asked first - is there a file `/bin/dash`?

Comment: @Zanna No! It doesn't exist

Comment: How strange... try `sudo apt install --reinstall dash`

Comment: @Zanna `Reinstallation of dash is not possible, it cannot be downloaded`. It makes me crazy! Nothing works correctly!!!

Comment: I wonder what happened - what might you or someone else have done to cause it? Very odd that it would just disappear

Comment: The day before this problem arise, I turned the laptop on and then didn't use it. I didn't even login! But everything was ok, gui, internet connection! And after a long time I turned it off from login page. I'm wondering what has caused this weird situation!

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /bin/sh`?

Comment: I think your bash is replaced by something else accidentally. I'd advice to boot up a bootable usb anf copy the bash, sh files from it to your installation

Comment: @KazWolfe `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 ■■■■■ 9 11:19 /bin/sh -> dash`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like your `/bin/sh` and/or your `/bin/dash` executable got borked somehow.

First, let's try to reinstall `dash`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall dash
```

Then, reboot. If your system still doesn't work,  we just need to relink it to `/bin/dash` using this command:

```
sudo ln -fs /bin/dash /bin/sh
```

Give your machine a reboot just to ensure everything is cleared out of memory, and then try logging in.

The `-f` option on `ln` will force the system to build a link, even though the file already exists.

---

If your system complains that `dash` can not be downloaded, run this command to install the latest version from the Xenial repos directly.

If you have a 64-bit system (the majority of people):

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dash/dash_0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb -qO dash.deb && sudo dpkg -i dash.deb && rm dash.deb
```

If you have a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dash/dash_0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2_i386.deb -qO dash.deb && sudo dpkg -i dash.deb && rm dash.deb
```

You can check your architecture by running `arch`. If it returns `x86_64`,  you have a 64-bit system. Otherwise, you have a 32-bit system or some weird system.

Comment: I tried `wget http ...` for 32-bit system, it didn't output anything and then I rebooted the system and I am still in tty mode! :(

Comment: @01000110 Are you sure you're on a 32-bit computer? Also note that you'll need to type it in ***exactly*** as it appears in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that it's 32-bit and typed it correctly. Maybe there is a problem with the internet connection?

Comment: @01000110 Run the part of the command before the first `&&` and remove the `q` from the `-qO` and see what the output is. (So, just `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dash/dash_0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2_i386.deb -O dash.deb`)

Comment: `failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. wget: unable to resolve host address archive.ubuntu.com` !!

Comment: I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the first line of `/etc/resolv.conf` and re-run the command. now it says `dash.deb saved`.

Comment: Now by executing `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dash/dash_0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2_i386.deb -O dash.deb && sudo dpkg -i dash.deb && rm dash.deb` I get this Error: `dpkg: warning: 'sh' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable`

Comment: @01000110 Oh boy. That's fun. Can you come [meet me in a chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56962/sh-woes) to solve this issue?